# Logarithmic algorithm performance

Tags: algorithms, special-functions

If I have an algorithm that on $T$ iterations gets me within $O(\log(T)/T)$ accuracy, what is a (preferably concise, closed form) lower bound on $T$ that gets me within $\epsilon$ accuracy?

In other words,
$$T \geq g(\epsilon) \implies \frac{\log(T)}{T} \leq \epsilon.$$
Find $g(\epsilon)$.

Comment: I'm curious why you tagged this as convex-analysis and convex-optimization, since it is neither.

Comment: I was in a hurry, I guess because it arose out of some convex analysis/optimization work, but you're right, its not.

Answer (score 1):

For $\epsilon\leq 1/e$, 
$$T \geq e^{-W_{-1}(-\epsilon)}=-\epsilon^{-1}W_{-1}(-\epsilon)$$ where $W_{-1}$ is the second branch of the [Lambert $W$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). The Lambert $W$ functions are branches of the inverse of $f(z)=ze^z$.

It cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions, so this is the best you can do.

Answer courtesy [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+Log%5BX%5D%2FX+%3D+A).